# WinError 10057 A request to send or receive data was disallowed

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, max

New to the community and Python, so bear with me here. I created a program that uses Tesseract OCR to identify a string/character of text in real-time. I am now trying to send that text to a UDP port on my own computer so that I can receive the output in Max/MSP. See the code below:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
import socket

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 8000

cntr =0;
while True:
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    cntr= cntr+1;
    if ((cntr%20)==0):
        imgH, imgW,_ = frame.shape
        x1,y1,w1,h1 = 0,0,imgH,imgW
        imgchar = pytesseract.image_to_string(frame)
        imgchar_b = str.encode(imgchar)
        print("UDP target IP: %s" % UDP_IP)
        print("UDP target port: %s" % UDP_PORT)
        print("message: %s" % imgchar)
        sock = socket.socket(socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.sendto(imgchar_b, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
        cv2.imshow('test',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF ==ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The full error is "[WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied."

I did not receive the error until I introduced the sock & sock.sendto lines into the code. Admittedly, I do not have a great understanding of what I am doing--I am using this for an interactive media project, and my background is in the arts. Both Max/MSP and Python programs are enabled for network purposes. If anyone has a solution to this issue, a simpler way of sending real-time Python outputs to Max/MSP, or any other suggestions, please let me know!

Comment: Not related to your error, but recreating the socket on (potentially) every loop iteration is bad. Create it one time above the loop, and then reuse it inside the loop.

Comment: Does _any_ of the `pytesseract` and `cv2` code have to do with the question you're asking? It seems you could remove everything but the socket creation and `sendto` call.

Comment: Please read the post again. The pytesseract and cv2 code is identifying strings of text in real-time. I want to send that text, being identified in real-time, to Max/MSP. The question is how I can get this real-time generated text sent to Max/MSP via UDP. I'll leave it up to you to determine whether that's important

Comment: We can see that, but _what_ you send doesn't matter and you should preferably leave things that doesn't matter to the problem you're trying to solve out of the question (to make it easier for people to identify the problem and help out).

Comment: @dumbmastersstudent the problem is not with WHAT you are sending, but HOW you are sending it. So, you can effectively remove all details about the WHAT and focus only on asking about the HOW.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing a socket is done with this call:

> `class socket.socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, fileno=None)`

So, the correct way to create the socket would be to supply the *family* argument first and *type* second, like this:

```py
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

or like this (since the *family* argument defaults to `socket.AF_INET`):

```
sock = socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

The way you call it means that you supply the *type* `SOCK_DGRAM` as the *family* argument and that the *type* defaulted to `SOCK_STREAM` - which is a connected (TCP) socket type. Since this socket wasn't actually connected when you did `sendto`, it failed.

This minimal example where I've removed the pytesseract and cv2 code works:

```py
#!/bin/python

import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 8000

sock = socket.socket(type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(b"Hello world", (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Comment: To elaborate why the original code failed, it was passing `SOCK_DGRAM` to the `family` parameter of the `socket()` constructor, not to the `type` parameter. The `type` parameter defaults to `SOCK_STREAM` (ie, connection-oriented), and the protocol parameter defaults to 0. Since `AF_INET` and `SOCK_DGRAM` both have a numeric value of 2, thus calling `socket(SOCK_DGRAM)` is effectively the same as calling `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)`, ie creating a TCP socket. So the code was calling `sendto()` on a TCP socket that wasn't connected to a remote peer, hence the `WSAENOTCONN` error.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, good explanation. I put some of it in the answer too. Thanks.